# How to post complex type to WCF using Python's requests?

Tags: python, wcf, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to query a WCF web service using Python's [request](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) package.

I created a very simple web service in WCF, following the default VS template:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IHWService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method="GET", UriTemplate="SayHello", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string SayHello();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetData", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetData2", BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,  RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}
```

From Python, I manage to call the first two and get the data back easily.

However, I am trying to call the third one, which adds the concept of complex types.

This is my python code:

```
import requests as req
import json

wsAddr="http://localhost:58356/HWService.svc"
methodPath="/GetData2"

cType={'BoolValue':"true", 'StringValue':'Hello world'}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
result=req.post(wsAddr+methodPath,params=json.dumps({'composite':json.dumps(cType)}),headers=headers)
```

But it does not work, i.e., if I put a breakdown in VS in the `GetDataUsingDataContract` method, I see that the `composite` argument is `null`. I think this comes from a problem in parsing, but I can't quite see what's wrong.

Do you see an obvious mistake there?

Do you know how I can debug inside the parsing mechanism?

**EDIT**:

Here is the complex type definition:

```
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    bool boolValue = true;
    string stringValue = "Hello ";

    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send JSON in the *POST body*, but you are attaching it to the query parameters instead.

Use `data` instead, and only encode the *outer* structure:

```
result=req.post(wsAddr+methodPath,
                data=json.dumps({'composite': cType}),
                headers=headers)
```

If you encoded `cType`, you'd send a JSON-encoded string containing another JSON-encoded string, which in turn contains your `cType` dictionary.

Comment: Actually, now the type is not null anymore but both fields are not initialized. I'll add the custom type definition to the question

Comment: @SRKX: I have no idea how JSON maps to WCF types though.

Comment: Found it! Just have to make `BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest` (not Bare) in the WebInvoke attribute. Thanks a lot.