# call windows service wcf from website using python

Tags: c#, python, point-of-sale

I have website build using python and I want to connect with point of sell in the client side 
there is any way to send data and get result from windows service or any other way ?

Comment: I asked for communication way between javascript and windows service or any thing like this

Answer (score 0):

You can create and send an HTTP/HTTPS request according to the configuration and specification of the WCF of the service you want to use.
[WCF and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/276184/9014308)
[How to post complex type to WCF using Python's requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24492507/9014308)

However, it may not be possible.
[WCF with netTcpBinding + cPython](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31266930/9014308)

Please start with obtaining service specifications.